# looking for how to make my own MessageBox sample code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox

looking for how to make my own MessageBox sample code

something simple that has title, body text and yes/no button

and how to use it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is a [built-in method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z.aspx) for this. It will automatically display a message box on screen with your specified parameters. For example, the following line of code:

```
MessageBox.Show("Your body text goes here.",
                "Message Title",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

will produce a message box that looks like this:

[image: sample message box]

You can also specify an icon for your message box using a [different overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y.aspx) of the [`MessageBox.Show` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx). For example:

```
MessageBox.Show("Your body text goes here.",
                "Message Title",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

The complete list of icon values is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon.aspx).

The **return value** of the `MessageBox.Show` function is a [`DialogResult` value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) corresponding to the button that was clicked on the message box. By checking the return value, you can determine which course of action was chosen by the user. For example:

```
private void QueryExitApplication()
{
    // Show a message box, asking the user to confirm that they want to quit
    DialogResult result;
    result = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to quit this application?",
                             "Quit Application?",
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    // Check the returned value of the MessageBox.Show function
    // (this corresponds to the button clicked by the user)
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // Close the form
        this.Close();
    }

    // Otherwise, they selected No (so do nothing)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom dialog boxes as given here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/A_Custom_Message_Box.aspx

Comment: Ugh, why would you want a hideous looking message box like that? You're allowed to use the built-in one. It's free. You don't have to do a worse job reinventing your own.

Comment: And if you want to use the built one, here you can find some details http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/MessageBoxEx.aspx